Troubleshooting SSH Connection Issues on WSL
I'm currently setting up OCaml on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and encountering issues with SSH authentication when trying to connect to GitLab. Despite multiple attempts to generate SSH keys (both RSA and ED25519), I keep getting the error message: "git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey)."
Here are the steps I've followed for generating and adding SSH keys:
RSA Key Generation:

Generated the key with ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@example.com".
Started the SSH agent with eval "$(ssh-agent -s)".
Added the key to the SSH agent using ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.
Added the public key to GitLab.
Tested the connection with ssh -T git@gitlab.com, expecting "Welcome to GitLab, @myUsername!" but received "Permission denied (publickey)."

ED25519 Key Generation:

Generated the key with ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "myemail@example.com".
Started the SSH agent with eval "$(ssh-agent -s)".
Added the key to the SSH agent using ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.
Added the public key to GitLab.
Tested the connection with ssh -T git@gitlab.com, expecting "Welcome to GitLab, @myUsername!" but received "Permission denied (publickey)."

Additional Attempts: I also tried importing my existing SSH key from another machine by copying the keys from my Windows file system to WSL. After copying, I followed the previous steps to add the keys to the SSH agent and GitLab but received the same error.
If required I can provide the output to the command ssh -vvvT git@gitlab.com
Any help on resolving this would be greatly appreciated!
The output of running ssh -Tv -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@gitlab.com was:
OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [172.65.251.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GitLab-SSHD
debug1: compat_banner: no match: GitLab-SSHD
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:eUXGGm1YGsMAS7vkcx6JOJdOGHPem5gQp4taiCfCLB8
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 does not exist
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (172.65.251.78)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:eUXGGm1YGsMAS7vkcx6JOJdOGHPem5gQp4taiCfCLB8.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ping@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: myEmail@example.com ED25519 SHA256:EYG3mvvWn/tBNsq3wWH/TOzYRnS6eozTJxxEU9b1JRw agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ef6Y43GZ0muC73Cj97vnIS8sH5bn+GXjxEnNWYEsk/Q explicit
debug1: Offering public key: myEmail@example.com ED25519 SHA256:EYG3mvvWn/tBNsq3wWH/TOzYRnS6eozTJxxEU9b1JRw agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ef6Y43GZ0muC73Cj97vnIS8sH5bn+GXjxEnNWYEsk/Q explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
And the output of running ssh -Tv -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 git@gitlab.com was:
OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [172.65.251.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GitLab-SSHD
debug1: compat_banner: no match: GitLab-SSHD
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:eUXGGm1YGsMAS7vkcx6JOJdOGHPem5gQp4taiCfCLB8
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myUsername/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ping@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:EYG3mvvWn/tBNsq3wWH/TOzYRnS6eozTJxxEU9b1JRw explicit agent
debug1: Offering public key: /home/myUsername/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:EYG3mvvWn/tBNsq3wWH/TOzYRnS6eozTJxxEU9b1JRw explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Please show us the text output from ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com. Preferably for both keys:  ssh -Tv -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@gitlab.com, ssh -Tv -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 git@gitlab.com

As a troubleshooting step, maybe you can run your procedure on Windows to exclude the possiblity specific to WSL.

I have provided outputs to the commands you requested. @phd

Client: "Offering public key", server: rejected. Somehow GitLab hasn't got your public key. Not uploaded, or uploaded to wrong field, or uploaded in wrong form, broken.

I’m almost certain I uploaded both to gitlab correctly though.

Just checked and both keys are uploaded correctly but gitlab still isn't accepting either public keys. @phd

@JacobParsons I'm out of ideas, sorry.
